# How to make a file "non-admin"

Tags: windows-7, usb, virtualbox, administrator, portable-apps

I have this portable virtual box i have in my USB.

[image]

As you can see on the above image it is called `Portable-VirtualBox.exe`(That directory is in my USB) . And if you look closely you can see an admin image, that tells you have to run it via admin . (bottom right of icon of Application). Well how do I delete that, so anyone can run that application? And I want it to stay like that in any computer (so I don't have to run via admin). Help would be appreciated.

**Note : **
I'm trying to do this on a school-provided computer, so I cant access Control Panel, nor can I use Command prompt; and, of course, I don't have administrative rights. The purpose for which I intend to use VirtualBox is to run osDev in a VM in order to develop a kernel.

Comment: There isn't much that can be done to an application as the end user, if it requires elevated persmissions to run, if that is required or not is determined by the program itself and its manifest file.  Even if you change the manifest file, if the program requires the elevated permissions to function, if you don't eslate the process the application simply won't function correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the application.
If you set it to "always start as admin" yourself then you can undo this in the compatibility tab of the properties windows of the file.

If you didn't do that then there is a big chance that the developer of the application "told" its application it requires admin privileges.

If you are actually an admin and just are frustrated by the pop ups asking if you really are sure then you could disable UAC
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-user-account-control-uac-the-easy-way-on-windows-vista/

Comment: Im trying to do this in a school computer, so i cant go to control panel at all lol.. cant even go to terminal. And if you ask why, well i do osDev and i want to osdev in my programming classes.

Comment: What i used to do when i was in school was set up an RDP connection to my PC at home. ofc hoping they allow port 3389. if they dont you could try setting up a RDGateway which will connect over port 443 which is unlikely to be blocked. if all else fails perhaps teamviewer, not 100% sure if it requires admin privs

Comment: Im testing teamviewer right now. thanks for that suggestion!

Comment: Kage : seems like i can connect to my dads computer via teamviewer, hope i can do same there at school . But can i make it fullscreen?

Comment: When you have a teamviewer connection open, there is a bar with options, in the bottom left corner there is a small icon to go fullscreen

Answer (score -1):

Right click your executable, go to the **compatibility** tab, and there should be an option **Run this program as an administrator**.

Comment: Yes , but that is not what i want... at all " 
Im trying to do this in a school computer, so i cant go to control panel at all lol.. cant even go to terminal. And if you ask why, well i do osDev and i want to osdev in my programming classes"

Comment: Ask permission from your System administrator and try to get access that way.

Comment: That will never happen. "Ask Permission", to osdev? Haha :D

Comment: No, you said it's on school PC's, if you really want to use a certain application, ask your school system admin for permission.

Comment: Can you stop telling me that @JustDenDimi ? Im never gonna do that, and i already told you so . I dont ask for Adminstrator Priv. and even if i do , they would say no. Schools dont care about programming these days so, it would be a guarrante they will say no

Comment: If your school doesn't care that's very unfortunate. Also, indeed as said by @Kage you could use remote control, if teamviewer doesn't work, windows also has a built in tool for this called Remote Desktop, you can always try that if it doesn't work, but it requires some set-up.

Comment: Teamviewer works , trying to find tricks to make it faster

Comment: Since it's over an internet connection, it'll always have some lag to it. When you're connected to the other computer, at the top you can change the 'view' setting to optimise for speed. That should help a little. ^^

Comment: The OP doesn't have admin privileges, so this isn't possible. @Dsafds: the answer author is trying to help, so please try to be nice.

Comment: @Dsafds Chrome remote desktop works; P.S. OP of this answer is just trying to be helpful, you don't have to be rude. If your systems administrator doesn't want you doing stuff like osDev (on a school computer), you're just gonna have to get over it.. We're not going to try to help you do something that is most likely against your school policies.

Comment: @varfirstName I use teamviewer for Desktop, and chrome desktop for my tablet

Comment: @bwDraco This is 100% Possible... Many Ways to achieve this

Comment: @Dsafds Draco is referring to doing so on the local machine (i.e. the school computer). I recommend you get Chrome Remote Desktop for your desktop as well because I find it to be more reliable. You could also try making your Desktop into a VNC server.